# Z-Index for an absolute positioned block

Tags: css, position, z-index, absolute

I have a so called "drop-down" list created this way:

HTML:

```html
<span><img src="images/searchall.png" alt=""/>
  <ul>
    <li>WORKSPACES</li>
    <li>REPORTS</li>
    <li>PEOPLE</li>
    <li>COMMENTS</li>
    <li>ANNOTATIONS</li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

CSS:

```css
span {position:relative;}
span ul {position:absolute; display:none;}
span:hover > ul {display:block;}
```

My problem is that the ul should appear on `span:hover` under the `img` element inside the `span`. I've tried setting index for all elements but it simply doesn't work.

What do I have to do?

P.S.: I know that I have some mark-up problems for that `ul` inside the `span`. No worry. I'll fix. The graphic problem is more important at the moment! Thanks

Comment: I'm not having a problem. http://dabblet.com/gist/5022942 Maybe it's your browser

Comment: Exactly what you have seems to work perfectly... http://jsfiddle.net/XLzmc/

Comment: try to change the `span` to `div` first

Answer (score 0):

```
span ul { z-index: 100; }
span:hover img { z-index: 101; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS file:

```
span {position:relative;}
span ul {position:absolute; min-height:20px;}
span ul li {display:none;}
ul:hover > li {display:block;}
```

Always displace `ul` to control `li`

Comment: Well, still not working. :( http://i.minus.com/ib2DUlorojZFdz.png, something like this i have to get!

Answer (score 0):

See does this work as the way you want:

```
span {float:left; width:200px;}
span img{float:left; width:200px;}
span ul {float:left; display:none;}
span:hover > ul {display:block;}
```

You should float all the block element and define their size, so the box can assign vertically.

Answer (score 0):

It seemly you only consider IE7+. if you want ul under img, you should give img a z-index that more than the z-index of ul, but please consider that some content of ul under img isn't visible. `jsfiddle.net/XLzmc/1/`

Comment: I finaly figured it out. This + {position: relative} for the img elemend did the thing.

Comment: yes, set position:relative|absolute|fixed along with z-index, with the defualt value position:static, z-index has no effect.